# Visual studio c++ debugger unable to read memory when entering if statement

Tags: c++, debugging, scope, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017. "resources" which is a private member of the class's function in the images. Once I step into Line 3101 all information associated with "resources" is lost at Line 3103. By this I mean, all members are marked as "unable to read memory" or ??? in the watch dialog.

Originally, I thought there was another thread that was altering this structure however this does not appear to be the case. I can drag the debug line between 3090 and 3103 and you can see that the ability to debug resources is gained (at line 3090) and lost (at line 3103).

First Debug Hit on Line 3090:
[image: First Debug Hit on Line 3090]

First Debug Hit on Line 3105:
[image: First Debug Hit on Line 3105]

Brought debugger back to Line 3090:
[image: Brought debugger back to Line 3090]

Second Debug Hit on Line 3105:
[image: Second Debug Hit on Line 3105]

Comment: Looks like the variable got nuked for reasons that are not immediately apparent in the provided example. Consider manufacturing a [mre] and in the future don't depend so heavily on images. They aren't nearly as useful as a good, isolated example presented in text that a potential answerer can drop into their tools and investigate themselves.

Comment: Are you running Debug project configuration? In Release, you can still debug, but some variables are optimized away.

Comment: I recommend viewing the assembly language listing for your function.  You can then see if the variable was put into a register or not.  The assembly language listing will also show if variables were optimized away (for example, if a variable is no longer used in a section of code).

Comment: @user4581301 I would think if I can produce a minimal reproducible example I would be able to create the issue and thus know the root cause and how to fix it. In which case I would not have to post the questions??? I have been using this particular variable for over a year with no issues just not sure why it is an issue all of a sudden for this particular part of the code. while in this particular else if statement.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for the comment. I am in debug mode and Mixed platform. I can definitely debug and view the objects members anywhere in the code I would expect it to be visible (i.e. in scope). It just seems to be this particular else if statement where the debugger seems to not have information on the object.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have never done that before but I will look into it more. I would say that the variable definitely does get used later in this section of code (sorry you would not know that by the amount of code in the image). Additionally, it is used in other places later and should be contained for the life of the mfc dialog that is the class in the image. With that said, I will look into your suggestion.

Comment: If the `if` statement you are debugging is in native code, you may be better off using native debugger mode.

Comment: @siberian The point of asking for a MRE is making a MRE leads the asker to finding and fixing the bug themselves most of the time, and when it doesn't, the asker usually has a pretty good question. I'll admit that some questions are highly resistant to making a MRE, and I'll also admit I didn't read the question as well as I could have. IOn re-read it looks like the question is more a "Why is this happening?" as opposed to "I have bug here. How do I fix it?" and a MRE's not always that useful for this case.

Comment: @user4581301 okay you are right... if I would have created a minimal viable product I may have found the issue. see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a coworker introduces a variable with the same name of the class scoped "resources" variable inside of the "else if" statement on line 3101. So what was happening was that when I stepped into this level it appears that the debugger was looking for information associated with the not yet initialized local to the "else if" "resources" variable and not the class scoped "resources" variable.

The interesting thing is that the class instance of resources was still able to referenced inside the "else if" scope and return the expected values but the debugger was not able to provide the desired information for inspection. Still not sure how the mechanics of this works out for the debugger but simply changing the name of the "else if" scoped "resource" variable fixed the problem with the debugger not having information associated with the class scoped resource variable.